pipeline npm install issues
pipeline.yml file:
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '21.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

I am running the job in self-hosted agent in the oracle vm. Pipeline seems to always fail when installing npm. Error is an assertion error with. Reads as:
 Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\agent\_work\_temp\97407895-4ccc-4e26-92bd-12c6df490d71.cmd""
Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file c:\ws\deps\uv\src\win\core.c, line 327
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '-1073740791'.
Finishing: npm install and build

I have synced the time on both my local and vm machines but the error keeps occurring and the job keeps failing.
I also am unable to locate the directory c:\ws\deps\uv\src\win\ in my VM.

The error you’re encountering seems related to a known issue with Node.js and its dependency, libuv.
Here is the issue detail for your reference: Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file c:\ws\deps\uv\src\win\core.c  and Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time.
The solutions you can try:

Go to Date & Time settings and clicking on the “Synchronize Your Clock” button.
Try to download and install the latest NodeJS from the download page
Try the node version with a fix mentioned in this answer.

